# Android: wrong orientation of files opened with BitmapFactory.decodeFile

Tags: android, resize, exif, bitmapfactory

Just simple as the title, files opened with BitmapFactory.decodeFile have wrong orientation when it is displayed on the ImageView. The image its captured from the camera and saved on a tmp file so if the device has the bug that returns data.getData() null I have at least a reference to the file.

This just start the camera activity and capture the image file

```
private void startCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (hasImageCaptureBug()) {
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(Constants.TMPFILE_PATH)));
    } else {
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = null;

            if (hasImageCaptureBug()) {
                File f = new File(Constants.TMPFILE_PATH);
                try {
                    uri = Uri.parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), f.getAbsolutePath(), null, null));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                }
            } else {
                uri = data.getData();
            }

            imageFilePath = Image.getPath(this, uri);

            if (Image.exists(imageFilePath)) {
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                int targetW     = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.thumbnail_screen_width);
                int degrees     = (int) Image.getRotation(this, uri);

                Bitmap bmp = Image.resize(imageFilePath, targetW);
                bmp = Image.rotate(bmp, degrees);

                image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this file resizes the image

```
public class Image {
    public static Bitmap resize(String pathName, int targetW) {
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, opts);

        int photoW = opts.outWidth;
        int photoH = opts.outHeight;
        int targetH = Math.round((photoH * targetW) / photoW);
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        opts.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        opts.inPurgeable = true;

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, opts);

        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Tryed to get the ExifOrientation but always its 0 because the file itself its correctly oriented just when I load it the file is displayed with the wrong orientation.

Regards

Comment: I dont remember exactly how to do this, but if I remember correctly you have to query the media store for ORIENTATION

Comment: There is a HARDWARE bug in certain phones that rotate the image. There isn't a set direction they rotate, some left, some right. The devs know about it, but since it's a hardware issue, there's not much they can do. I haven't seen a wok around but I haven't done any wok on my camera app in a while.

Comment: @TomFobear dont remember if try with media query method, let me check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that my issue to preview the image was the Constants.TMPFILE_PATH, the image was not saved there, I just use this fix [Display the latest picture taken in the image view layout in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107168/display-the-latest-picture-taken-in-the-image-view-layout-in-android)!, but the issue persist if I post it to the server... I'll check this as answered and open a new question to this...

---

Edited

To solve this issue just refactor the new image and then upload it to the server, because the raw data of the file itself has his exif orientation was wrong.